# Using sympy to rearrange equation?

Tags: python, sympy, equation

Im trying to rearrange a supply curve equation for calculation the price elasticy.

The equation is `log P = -2 + 1.7 * log Q`.

Im trying to rearrange the equation so that log Q is in terms of log P. Is there a way sympy can handle these rearrangements?

```py
p, q = sp.symbols('p, q', real=True, positive=True)

eq = sp.Eq(-2+1.7*sp.log(q))

sp.solve(eq,sp.log(p))
```

Comment: There is no `p` in the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Using sympy solve will take care of the arrangements. The equations just must be set up properly and the function parameters must be correct.

```
import sympy as sp

p, q = sp.symbols('p, q', real=True, positive=True)
eq = sp.Eq(-2+1.7*sp.log(q), p) # set equation = to p
ans = sp.solve(eq,q) #solve equation for q in terms of p
```

This solution simply saves your equation to eq and solves eq for q so the answer is in terms of only p. In the end ans holds the value:

```
[3.24290842192454*exp(0.588235294117647*p)]
```

I highly reccomend reading [this](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html) website before coming to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Although you showed `log P` in the written text, you did not include it in the code. If you do so, you can then request that `solve` isolate `log(q)` for you:

```py
>>> eq = Eq(log(p), -2 + 10*log(q)/17)
>>> solve(eq, log(q))
[17*log(p)/10 + 17/5]
```